# WCF Net.Pipe cannot be found in WCF Test Client

Tags: wcf

I have a console application that acts as a WCF endpoint.

When I add it in WCF Test client, all is fine. However, the endpoint that I have specified for net.pipe is not.

I've already added WCF Non-HTTP Activation, rebooted the PC and it's still not working.

Any ideas on what else I need to do?
Thanks